# Support Vector Machine is outputting two zeros in Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

I am working on an ML project to predict a particular boolean column. 
I am using SVM's in SKlearn. I have some features I am trying to use as my descriptive features. These features contain integers (label encoding) and have a max of three unique values.
The confusion matrix and classification report that is produced after I make the prediction is down below. I can't understand why it is classifying zero results. Any help? [image of code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfpPY.png)

The code below is using one descriptive feature that contains three unique integers, and the target feature is a boolean column.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
array([[9309,    0],
       [8896,    0]], dtype=int64)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
      precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.51      1.00      0.68      9309
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00      8896

    accuracy                           0.51     18205
```

Here is the encoding and the training

```
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Gaze'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Gaze'])
df['Blink'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Blink'])
df['Brows'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Brows'])
df['QuestionType'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['QuestionType'])


y = df[['QuestionType']]
X = df[['Blush']]

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaling = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit(X_train)
X_train = scaling.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaling.transform(X_test)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = clf.decision_function(X_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: 1) include your code in the question instead of a link to an image. 2) your classifier is effectively `model = lambda x: 0`

Comment: Thank you! It's my first question so still getting used to this :D

Comment: Welcome. :) Can you also include the code that featurizes your inputs? It seems like your model isn't learning anything, so there's a good chance that's the problem.

Comment: Does that help??

Comment: Your code isn't complete, but it looks like your X is not encoded.

Comment: use LabelEncoder() to encode blush, encode.fit_transform(df['blush'])